# SpamAssassin trying to read config files under /root/

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, mailscanner

I have mail gateway servers configured to use MailScanner + Postfix + SpamAssassin as described [here](http://www.mailscanner.info/postfix.html), along with [MailWatch](http://mailwatch.sourceforge.net/) as a web front end.

When sa-learn is run from MailWatch (it's run as the postfix user), it throws this error:

```
SA Learn: config: path "/root/.spamassassin" is inaccessible: Permission denied, Learned tokens from 0 message(s) (1 message(s) examined)
```

Running "sudo -u postfix spamassassin --lint -D" gives this bit of info:

```
dbg: config: read file /etc/mail/spamassassin/mailscanner.cf
warn: config: path "/root/.spamassassin" is inaccessible: Permission denied
dbg: config: mkdir /root/.spamassassin failed: mkdir /root/.spamassassin: Permission denied at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Mail/SpamAssassin.pm line 1577
dbg: config: Permission denied
dbg: config: using "/etc/MailScanner/spam.assassin.prefs.conf" for user prefs file
```

The bayes tokens are learned correctly, however this error is a minor annoyance and I'd like to fix it... Either by forcing SpamAssassin to not check the /root/.spamassassin/ directory for the config & prefs, or to fix MailWatch so it calls sa-learn correctly & doesn't throw this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real fix is to disable "per-user" config in spamassassin and globally set the Baysean DB, but a quick patch would be to add the "-H" option to sudo to use postfix's home directory where it should have permission to write as postfix.

Comment: This sounds like it might be along the correct lines, but I'm still looking for specific documentation on how to accomplish this... once I do & if it turns out to be correct, I'll post it here and check this as answered unless someone beats me to the punch.

Comment: Of course the other option is to symlink /root/.spamassassin to ~postfix/.spamassassin
I've done this on one machine and it does work as long as the permissions are ok.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug it is because you are running the sa-learn command with an invalid user. For example my setup uses the standard debian-spamd user.

```
# sa-learn -u debian-spamd --dbpath /var/lib/spamassassin/.spamassassin/bayes --dump magic
0.000          0          3          0  non-token data: bayes db version
0.000          0         84          0  non-token data: nspam
0.000          0       6565          0  non-token data: nham
0.000          0      15128          0  non-token data: ntokens
0.000          0 1510837441          0  non-token data: oldest atime
0.000          0 1519232775          0  non-token data: newest atime
0.000          0          0          0  non-token data: last journal sync atime
0.000          0          0          0  non-token data: last expiry atime
0.000          0          0          0  non-token data: last expire atime delta
0.000          0          0          0  non-token data: last expire reduction count
```

And for accounts

```
# sa-learn --ham -u debian-spamd --showdots --dir /var/vmail/mydomain.com/support/cur/*
.
Learned tokens from 1 message(s) (1 message(s) examined)
```

I have 20 email accounts on the server and crons to match for ham and spam and never the error. Make sure your setup and user:group correct on relevant files/directories.

Link to a quick tutorial on how to fix
https://www.devcu.com/forums/topic/745-spamassassin-is-inaccessible-permission-denied/

Answer (score 1):

This could be a workaround:

```
# chmod o+x /root
# mv -f /root/.spamassassin /root/.spamassassin.err
# ln -s /var/spool/MailScanner/spamassassin /root/.spamassassin
# mkdir -p /var/spool/MailScanner/spamassassin
# chown postfix.apache /var/spool/MailScanner/spamassassin
# chmod 770 /var/spool/MailScanner/spamassassin
```

Comment: This was my original thought for a workaround, but making /root traversable by anyone doesn't really give me the warm fuzzies... While I don't think it's necessarily a security risk, I'd rather avoid it if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use the spamassassin daemon *spamd* instead? Then you'd use the *spamc* command instead of spamassassin. Basically, run *spamd* from its startup script, and use *spamc* from your mailscanner.

Comment: MailScanner doesn't actually use spamd, spamc, or the spamassassin script directly, it calls the installed perl modules.

Comment: I see. Then you should tell sa-learn to use some other place ( postfix-writable) to store its data with the --dbpath option.

Comment: The bayes database is already writable by postfix, which is why tokens are being learned correctly - what I'm trying to fix is sa-learn checking the root directory for config files first & throwing an error before correctly using the global config file in /etc/MailScanner/ and moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding --dbpath parameter, like this ?

```
sa-learn --dbpath /var/lib/amavis/.spamassassin/ ....
```

Comment: Yup, and it still throws the "config: path "/root/.spamassassin" is inaccessible: Permission denied" error

Answer (score 0):

**The Cause**
The cause is that spamassassin (which is called by sa-learn, spamc, spamd, spampd etc), tries to read a per-user config file from $HOME.

This happens even if the config option *allow_user_rules* is set to 0 (IMO this is probably a bug and it's been round a ***long*** time).

As it can't find this folder (because of permissions) it then tries to create the folder.

As those who run sa-learn inside a cron know this is very annoying as we get a failure email even from a successful run.  Just google the error **config: path "/root/.spamassassin" is inaccessible: Permission denied** and see how many people this affects (and the insecure fixes they suggest).  The only safe solution for cron was to ignroe it and pipe stdout and stderr to /dev/null, but that's a bit extreme.

It does this regardless of what -C or -p or --dbpath options are passed, so you can't fix it either in the command line options or the global config.

**The Fix**
The solution, that worked for me, is to call sa-learn and pass a temporary $HOME environment variable pointing to a location where the non-root user running spamassassin can write, in my case this is /var/cache/spampd:
e.g.

```
HOME=/var/cache/spampd sa-learn --spam /var/vmail/jason/.SPAM/cur
```